# My records are not being inserted into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert records into MySQL database using PHP. Initially, the records were inserted into the database. After sometimes, it stopped inserting. There are no error messages displayed.

PHP code:

```
<?php
    require('dbconnect.php');
    if( isset($_POST['submit'] ) ){
        $fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
        $type=$_POST['type'];
        $price=$_POST['price'];
        $mmnumber=$_POST['mmnumber'];

        mysqli_query( $connect,"INSERT INTO `tickets`(fullname,type,price,mmnumber) VALUES('".$fullname."','".$type."','".$price."','".$mmnumber."')");
    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't know what `dbconnect.php` contains but nothing in the code you've shared instructs PHP to display error messages upon error. In any case, as already noted, you're injecting raw input into your SQL and executing it so your script should be expected to fail randomly depending on user input.

Answer (score 0):

I`t all about your *dbconnect.php* file and MySql connection *timeouts*.
Look for: [php.net mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php) and **MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT** setting.

When the connection timeout expires, the database connection goes down. So, you need to reconnect to DB or increase your timeout connection timer. Better way is reconnection. Try to check your connection and reconnect if it`s false:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* check if server is alive */

    if ($mysqli->ping()) {
        printf ("Our connection is ok!\n");
    } else {
       printf ("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
       $mysqli->close();
       $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why would a connection drop? What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: I'd check and my server is alive. but my problem is still not solved!